# Change background colour in Xterm

Tags: command-line, 16.04, colors, xterm

I want to change Xterm's (not the gnome terminal) background colour in Ubuntu 16.04 but there happens to be no title bar. I could not even find the Xresources file.

Also, I want the colour change to be permanent not just during that session. And one more thing I cannot execute any commands during that session because that Xterm window is being launched by some other program (to be specific that program is "Code Blocks").
Please help me sort out this issue.

Xterm screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you happened to don't have one, so create a file named `.Xresources` on your home directory:

```
touch ~/.Xresources
```

Then add following lines to `.Xresources` file:

```
xterm*Background: your_background_color
xterm*Foreground: your_foreground_color
```

example:

```
$ cat $HOME/.Xresources
XTerm.vt100.background: black
XTerm.vt100.foreground: grey
```

See [critical.ch/xterm](http://critical.ch/xterm) for a list of colors which may be supported in your version of XTerm.

You can either restart X or run `xdrb` command to apply change you have made:

```bash
xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
xterm
```

Comment: I did exactly what you explained, just added the colour names (white,black). But it did not help. Still the same.

Comment: Have you run `xrdb ~/.Xresources` command ?

Comment: Since you mentioned that either I should restart X or run xrdb. So I restarted->no good, ran xrdb->no good.
ran xrdb and restarted X->worked like a charm.
Thank you

Comment: Should we keep the `()` for the color?